# Are there any advantages with Simple products over Configurable products

Tags: magento

I need to import many products into Magento for a client.

I am not sure to set the type to Simple or Configurable. In the current state, all products are Simple. But I expect that the client will need some of the products to become "Configurable".

I therefore plan to import all products as Configurable. My question is, what is the downside of only using Configurable products? Are there any advantages with Simple products?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different colors or sizes (or other configurable options) you'll need to create simple products for every combination (small/red, medium/red, small/black, medium/black, etc) which you can do from within the configurable product screen, associated products tab.  If your product doesn't have any options, it should just be a simple product.

For reference, here is a page detailing the purpose of each product type: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype

Comment: Thanks for reply. But are there any advantages in using simple products over configurable products? Why not always use configurable products, even if there are no variants (size, color, etc)?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but it's probably slightly faster to use simple products.  Magento can assume certain things and doesn't have to perform additional checks/calls.  There also might be slight differences between the edit product pages.  In my opinion, it's kind of a matter of using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to use Magmi for large Magento imports. http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/
You can even have it create your configurable products automatically and it goes MUCH faster than magentos standard import. Like 1000's of products in seconds not hours.

My company has SKU101LG, SKU101MD, and SKU101XL (All simple products)

Therefore SKU101 is my configurable product with the above skus as its 'children' or as magento calls them 'associated products', based on their size attribute. 
(You have to create attributes such as size or color under CATALOG > ATTRIBUTES )

An Ipad is a simple product. And Ipad with color options is configurable, and has two OTHER skus (the simple skus for each color) associated to it.